# Passing inputs to program prompt in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd

I am running simulations in parallel using mpich2.  I've got rather stringent security on my workstation, and must register using a new password each time I run a simulation.  I have to enter:

```
mpiexec -register
```

which then prompt me for a username, and then prompt me for a password.  Unfortunately, there seem to be no way to pass the user/pass to mpiexec on a single line, e.g.

```
mpiexec -register user:pass
```

does not work.

I'm trying to prepare a batch file that can automatically pass the username and password to the mpiexec prompts, but I cannot seem to get it to work.  I've tried various things like `timeout /t 5` but that doesn't work.

Can anyone tell me how to pass these inputs to the mpiexec program prompts in a batch file?

Thanks!

EDIT: I think I am getting closer.  I've tried

```
(
echo username 
echo password 
echo password 
) | mpiexec -register
```

which appears to be passing the username and password inputs to the mpiexec prompts.  Program is still hanging at the next step however - not sure if that's a problem with the way I'm passing these or not.

Comment: Try this `((echo user)& (echo pass)) | mpiexec -register`. But this will only work when mpiexec reads from stdin

Comment: Hey jeb, thanks!  I'm not sure what stdin is.  I will give this a try but is it different from the EDIT that I entered above?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could redirect or pipe into `mpiexec`.
With redirection it's gets a bit nasty for user/password entries, as there are often unwanted (and unvisible) spaces at the line ends.

```
(
echo user
echo pwd
) | more > fetch.txt
```

Creates in `fetch.txt`

> user`<space>`
>   pwd`<space>`

When you want to suppress the spaces use a file redirection instead

```
(
echo user
echo pwd
) > file.tmp
< file.tmp mpiexec -register
```

In both cases (redirection or pipe), you need to serve **all inputs** for the program, not only username and password.
You can't enter inputs from keyboard anymore.